# How Do I Initialize OpenGL.NET with GLFW.Net?

Tags: c#, opengl, openglcontext

I am trying to use OpenGL and GLFW in C#. I Have Installed NuGet Packages for GLFW.Net and OpenGL.Net. What I cannot for my life figure out, is how do I setup the context for OpenGL.Net with GLFW.Net?? No error messages appeared when I tried to run my very basic test OpenGL Code. i.e.

```
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Glfw.Init();
            GLFWwindow window = Glfw.CreateWindow(1080, 720, "Yeet", null, null);
            Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window);
            Gl.Initialize();

            uint vao = Gl.CreateVertexArray();
            Gl.BindVertexArray(vao);

            uint vbo = Gl.CreateBuffer();
            Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            Gl.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 6, new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f }, BufferUsage.StaticDraw);
            Gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribType.Float, false, 0, null);

            while (Glfw.WindowShouldClose(window) != 1)
            {
                Glfw.PollEvents();

                Gl.ClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
                Gl.BindVertexArray(vao);
                Gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                Gl.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3);
                Gl.DisableVertexAttribArray(0);
                Gl.BindVertexArray(0);

                Glfw.SwapBuffers(window);
            }

            Glfw.DestroyWindow(window);
            Glfw.Terminate();
        }
    }
```

But Nothing Renders. Does this mean my Context does not exist or that I have been stupid and left something?

Comment: Does the color clear (to blue) work in your case?

Comment: No. Its probably the context creation then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first glace, I can see an obvious issue. The size of the buffer data has to be specified in bytes (see [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml)). Hence the size has to be 6*4 rather than 6:

```cs
var vertices = new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f };
Gl.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (uint)(4 * vertices.Length),
    vertices, BufferUsage.StaticDraw);
```

---

It turns out that the [OpenGL.NET](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/wiki) library has to be initialized before making the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) current (for whatever reason):

```cs
Gl.Initialize();
Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was move `Gl.Initialize()` Above `Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window)`. I guess you have to create the OpenGL context first and then make the context current. This is unlike LWJGL in which one must call `GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent()` before calling `GL.createCapabilities()`.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: I confirm. I have verified that.